# why do k-means clustering different results everytime?

Tags: matlab, k-means, image-segmentation

I am using k-means clustering for segmentation of retinal image. However everytime when I run my code segmentation yeilds different results for same image. What is the reason of this change? Following are three segmentation results of same image. [image: Segmentation result 1][image: Segmentation result 2][image: Segmentation 3]
Below is the code used for this segmenation.

```
idx = kmeans(double(imreslt1(:)),2);              
classimage =  reshape(idx, size(imreslt1));

               minD = min( classimage (:));
               maxD = max( classimage  (:));
               g = (double(classimage  ) - minD) ./ (maxD - minD);

imshow(g);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the initialization problem for kmeans, as when kmeans starts it picks up the random initial points to cluster your data. Then matlab selects k number of random points and calculates the distance of points in your data to these locations and finds new centroids to further minimize the distance. so because of these random initial points you get different results for centroid locations, but the answer is similar.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the reson of this change now :)

Comment: is there a way in matlab to statrt k-means with some fixed intial centroids so I can get desired result intead for re-running the code over and over.

Comment: IDX = KMEANS(X, K) partitions the points in the N-by-P data matrix
     ...
    'Start' - Method used to choose initial cluster centroid positions,
       sometimes known as "seeds". Choices are:
           ...
            matrix - A K-by-P matrix of starting locations. In this case,
                       you can pass in [] for K, and KMEANS infers K from
                       the first dimension of the matrix. You can also
                       supply a 3D array, implying a value for 'Replicates'
                       from the array's third dimension.

Comment: You can try as in below example if it helps(someone used this and it worked):
> >> load fisheriris
> >> m = grpstats(meas,species)
> m =
> 5.0060 3.4280 1.4620 0.2460
> 5.9360 2.7700 4.2600 1.3260
> 6.5880 2.9740 5.5520 2.0260
> >> g = kmeans(meas,3,'start',m);
> >> gplotmatrix(meas,[],g)
> >> crosstab(g,species)
> ans =
> 50 0 0
> 0 48 14
> 0 2 36   let me know if it worked for you

Comment: @ Preet I tried to use 'Start' parameter, but I am stille facing the same issue. Everytime I rum the code result is different.                                 [m,p] = size(imreslt1); %imreslt1- matrix on which k-means is applied
k=2; % Number of cluters
c = rand(k,1); % centroid should be k by p so k and 1. 
        idx = kmeans(double(imreslt1(:)),k,'Start',c);              
classimage =  reshape(idx, size(imreslt1));

               minD = min( classimage (:));
               maxD = max( classimage  (:));
               g = (double(classimage  ) - minD) ./ (maxD - minD);

Comment: view this post http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/144018 They made it work. hope it will help you

Comment: how do i decide the centroid values?

Comment: You can decide any values suits you its not something fixed. Just try few values and select one that gives best result for you. I n example as well they used random matrix for that

Comment: I used random matrix and that too is giving the same result as I was getting with out 'start' parameter.

Comment: have you read the whole documentation they also discussed the problem with stat toolbox version. try that as well if works

Comment: you can see this as well https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/74592-k-means-clustering-result-always-changes

Comment: https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92850-why-does-kmeans-return-different-results-when-invoked-on-the-same-input . This link solved my issue.

Comment: glad to know..!!

Answer (score 1):

If you read the MATLAB help file for the `kmeans` function, you'll see that the initial points for the k-means clustering algorithm are chosen randomly according to the k-means++ algorithm. To make this reproducible, you can either pass in your own initial points as follows:

```
kmeans(...,'Start',[random_points_matrix])
```

or, you could try seeding the MATLAB internal random number generator using the following:

```
rng(seed); % where seed is some constant you choose
idx = kmean(...);
```

However, I'm not clear on the internals of the `kmean` function, so I can't guarantee that this will necessarily produce reproducible results.